# Range reduction for the exponential integral?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, special-functions, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

I would like to compute $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ to a reasonable precision. Fortunately, I have a computer algebra system ([PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)) which includes this function as a built-in, but unfortunately, $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ causes an overflow. However, it's not that far away: I can compute $\operatorname{Ei}(x/8).$

Is there some sort of '[argument reduction](https://fredrikj.net/math/elefun.pdf)' strategy that would let me take advantage of the existing function, or do I need to code something from the ground up for this?

Comment: Up to what kind of value for $x$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici 10^19 or 10^20. My present interest is 1.27 * 10^19.

Comment: $\text{Ei}\left(10^5\right)=2.81\times 10^{43424}$ !!

Comment: Yes, and the Ei of my target value is about $10^{29441563680864526400},$ I believe. Big numbers, somewhat hard to work with.

Answer (score 1):

To a first estimate,
$$
\operatorname{Ei}(x) \approx \operatorname{Ei}(x/k)^k
$$
for $k$ small and $x$ large.

But we can improve on this with

$$
\operatorname{Ei}(x) = e^xf(x)
$$
where
$$
f(x)=\frac1x + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{6}{x^4} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)
$$
so
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) &= e^{x/k}f(x/k)\\
\log\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) &= x/k + \log f(x/k)\\
k\log\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) &= x + k\log f(x/k)\\
x &= k\log\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) - k\log f(x/k)\\
\end{array}
$$

and so

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\log\operatorname{Ei}(x) &= x + \log f(x)\\
\log\operatorname{Ei}(x) &= k\log\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) - k\log f(x/k) + \log f(x)\\
\operatorname{Ei}(x) &= \exp\big(k\log\operatorname{Ei}(x/k) - k\log f(x/k) + \log f(x)\big)\\
\operatorname{Ei}(x) &= \operatorname{Ei}(x/k)^kf(x)/f(x/k)^k\\
\end{array}
$$
which can be approximated with the series. Of course you can take any finite number of terms in $f$, but you can't remove the error term that way.

I'm sure there are better approaches but this is a decent quick-and-dirty approach.